# Is there a Jupyter API which given an IPython file outputs HTML code which can be put on my website?

Tags: ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I want to develop this as a service so that the service, when given an input IPython file, returns something which I can put up on my website.

Comment: Have you come across the Dashboards server? https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/dashboards_server

Comment: Please could you be a little more clear how this server might help. I get it that it is something useful but can't figure out the purpose exactly.

Comment: Someone with the extension installed decides which cells' output should be visible, and whether they want to change up the layout. Then they send the notebook to the dashboards server where it is served as a web page.

Answer (score 0):

Use [nbconvert](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert):

```
$ jupyter nbconvert --to html mynotebook.ipynb
```

This is a command line tool that converts a notebook to HTML.

Comment: I have a client server system. I upload the IPython files and the server should return me the output on the screen. So, should i install Jupyter on my server and run this command on the terminal whenever the file is uploaded? Plz explain

Comment: Is [nbviewer](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/) what you want? It's open source, so you can run your own instance if you need to.